# How to differentiate $\sqrt[5]{7x^2}$?

Tags: calculus

> How to differentiate $\sqrt[5]{7x^2}$?

I'm not sure how to do it.

I used the power and chain rules and have $\frac{14x}{5} \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{28x^8}}$.

Is this correct? I don't understand what to do next.

Comment: Don't you mean $\sqrt[5]{7x^2}$? And what more do you have to do? Your done aren't you? Though admittedly I have not yet verified it yet.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think that is a typo on the OP's part.

Comment: Okay. I fixed the problem. I thought the two meant the same thing.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.**  There's some confusion about whether you mean $\sqrt[5]{7}x^2$ or $\sqrt[5]{7x^2}$.

If the former, you have $Cx^2$, and the derivative of that is just $2Cx$.  If the latter, you have $Cx^{2/5}$, and the derivative of that is $\frac{2}{5}Cx^{-3/5}$.

Comment: I meant the latter, but I thought they meant the same thing.

Comment: What does the C represent? 7?

Comment: @user6050977: How could they mean the same thing?  An $x^2$ outside the radical clearly means something different from when it's inside in the radical. ¶ The $C$ represents the coefficient of the $x^2$ or $x^{2/5}$ term.  It would, in this case, be $\sqrt[5]{7}$.

Comment: It all looks the same to me. I probably have dyscalculia. If C is $\sqrt[5]{7}$, then how does the chain rule fit into this? My answer is totally different than what you posted above. Was there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

$(7x^2)^{1/5}=7^{1/5}\cdot x^{2/5}$ But then differentiating this doesn't need a chain rule at all:

$\frac{d}{dx}7^{1/5}\cdot x^{2/5}=7^{1/5}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot x^{-3/5}$

With your chain rule method:

$\frac{d}{dx}(7x^2)^{1/5}=7\cdot 2x\cdot(\frac{1}{5}(7x^2)^{-4/5})=7^{1/5}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot x^{-3/5}$

The very last equality takes a little bit of algebra, but I'll leave that to you!

Comment: I don't understand where $7^1/5$ comes from. Wouldn't it just be 14x multiplied by 1/5, to get 14x/5?

Comment: $7^{1/5} = \sqrt[5]7 $

Comment: I meant the part after "With your chain rule method."

Comment: I used http://www.derivative-calculator.net/ and its result is 2 times $\sqrt[5]{7}$ over $5x^3/5$. I don't understand why there is such a difference between what the website says, the many different answers given here and my own answer. Is this an impossible problem?

Comment: That is the exact same thing. You should spend some time reviewing algebra. Your problems arent with the calculus.

Comment: I also don't mean that comment to be offensive at all, I genuinely think that some problems would clear up if you reviewed exponent rules and square roots.

Comment: Okay, I think I see where my answer splits from the given ones.

http://imgur.com/IwGW2OY

I have the first part of that in my notebook, but I don't know how to properly phrase that in MathJax. The second part, I'm having trouble understanding. How would I get from the first part to the second?

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

$$\sqrt[5]{7x^2}=(7x^2)^{1/5}=7^{1/5}x^{2/5}=c\:x^a \quad \text{where} \begin{cases} c=7^{1/5} \\ a=2/5 \end{cases}$$
Do you know how to differentiate $\:c\:x^a\:$ ?

Comment: Is the next step the chain rule on a?

Comment: So, you don't know what is the derivative of 3x^2 for example ? and the derivative of cx^2? and the derivative of x^a? and the derivative of cx^a?

Comment: Isn't the first one 6x? I don't understand what to do with c in the other examples.

Comment: There is no need of chain rule. Do you use the chaine rule to differentiate 3x for example ?

Comment: Can the rule be used anyway? Math isn't intuitive. I can only do it by seeing how a problem is solved and then memorizing the exact pattern for future problems. I've never been able to understand written math explanations and concepts. If the pattern changes slightly, like in taking out the rule, then I can't solve the problem.

Comment: Then try to derivate these examples : What is the derivative of x ?, of 2x ?, of 7x ?, of nx?, of cx ?

Comment: Aren't those all 0?

Comment: NO ! For example the derivative of x in not 0. If you don't know that, you have to learn the basics.

Comment: I've never been able to understand math explanations, so I can't learn the basics. I'm hopeless at this.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-introduction.html

Comment: If you know that the derivative of x is 1, then what is the derivative of 2x ?

Comment: Is the answer 2?

Comment: yes. Then the derivative of 7x ?

Comment: Is the answer seven?

Comment: Yes; Now, the derivative of $n\,x$ ?

Comment: Is that just N? And C for cx?

Comment: Good ! Then the derivative of $x^3$ ?

Comment: $3x^2$? I think I understand simple differentiations. Its problems with multiple parenthesis and fractions like in the OP that I have trouble with.

Comment: So, now, you know the derivative of $c\,x^a$ ?

Comment: Is it ac$x^a-1$? I don't know how to do it in Mathjax... ^a-1...?

Comment: Yes, it is $acx^{a-1}$. In case of problems with multiple parenthesis and fractions you have to use the derivative rules. For example, see :  https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-rules.html .